# Non-scalar literals and querying in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, rdfs

Assume the runtime context here is Apache jena 3.4 and the ARQ query engine.
Consider the following triples:

```
:lib1  :makes   "Butter"
:lib2  :makes   "Bread"
```

It is straightforward to ask for the `:makes` property of `lib1` and `lib2` in a variety of ways, and a literal String is returned.  OK, great.
I wish, however, to externally manage a set of other attributes as a hashmap, e.g. (and this is not legal RDF):

```
:lib1  :attrs   {a:1, b:"hello", c:false}
```

This is because I want to keep the attrs grouped in the persistor backing the jena runtime and not exploded out into this:

```
:lib1  :attrs_a  1
:lib1  :attrs_b  "hello"
:lib1  :attrs_c  false
```

or:

```
:lib1  :attrs::a  1
:lib1  :attrs::b  "hello"
:lib1  :attrs::c  false
```

I can certainly do some additional manipulation of the data coming out of the persistor.   A thing that springs to mind is `subProperty`:

```
:attrs   rdf:type   rdf:Property
:a       rdfs:subPropertyOf  :attrs
:b       rdfs:subPropertyOf  :attrs
:c       rdfs:subPropertyOf  :attrs
```

and later

```
?resolveSubject ?p ?resolveObject .
?p rdfs:subPropertyOf+ :attrs
```

can be used to dynamically grab all the subProperties.  This works, although it is mildly irritating that the "parent" property `attrs` is also returned in the query; would like to see that go away without FILTER or some such.

**The Question**: Are there other best practice / practical tips+tricks around dealing with this sort of grouped, dynamic data?  Or does it quickly boil down to how to turn them into subproperties?

Comment: a) I don't think you are using `subProperty` as it is intended to be used. b) I would suggest to define a separate RDF class `LibAttrs` with the properties `{a,b,c}` that you will marshall by hand, while inserting into the Jena model a LibAttrs instance with a single property of the Redis (presumably?) key. So you would say `:lib1 attrs [ a LibAttrs; :a "1"; :b "hello"; :c false]` but marshall `LibAttrs` by hand and insert into the triplestore `:lib1 attrs [ a LibAttrs; :key "da8a0057fcb511185bf34de29fb83654"] .` or even `:lib1 attrkey "da8a0057fcb511185bf34de29fb83654" .` What is a persisor?

Comment: Easy Q first:   a persistor is a datastore/database.   Something that can vend the triples into code that can call model.add(...).
Harder:   Yeah, if I have a subClass then everything is easier except I end up with an instance of Attrs.   I don't wish to have each contained set of attrs have a unique instance name.   The subss are instead completely subordinated within the parent instance of Lib.   The type, however, is consistent across parents.

Answer (score 3):

A map like `{a:1, b:"hello", c:false}` isn't a particular complicated structure, and it's easy to represent in RDF.  It's an object that has three entries, and each entry associates a key with a value.  So, to approximate

```
:lib1  :attrs   {a:1, b:"hello", c:false}
```

you can simply do:

```
:lib1 :attrs [ :hasEntry [ :key "a"; :value 1 ] ,
                         [ :key "b"; :value "hello" ] ,
                         [ :key "c"; :value false ] ] .
```

Sure, it looks a little more verbose, but you've captured the whole structure of the triples are particularly complicated, especially if you're emitting these programmatically.

These also allow fairly easy query using SPARQL.  E.g., to ask for libraries and their "c" attributes, we can use a query like:

```
select ?lib ?value {
  ?lib :attrs/:hasEntry [ :key "c"; :value ?value ]
}
```

Comment: Hmmm!  Brackets....  So may I ask, in the context of Jena and the Java API where triples are added as (pseudocode) model.add(Resource, Property, Resource), how does one set that up?   It feels like 4 triples to add:
 {hasEntry,a,1},{hasEntry,b,hello},{hasEntry,c,false} followed by {lib1,attrs,hasEntry}    Yes?

Comment: @buzz, you might be interested in taking that rdf and serializing it as n-triples. That format has just one triple per line, so the exact triples to add will be explicit and clear.